# Protection of neighbours from dangerous dogs

Tags: dogs, safety, containment

My neighbour has 2 large Rottweilers. When these dogs jump up & stand on the wall, they stand at the height of the wall. Their property is lower than ours. We have had a previous incident of attack by a Rottweiler on our short dog.

Whose responsibility is it to ensure their safety, and what are the rules/laws with regards to safety of me from dangerous dogs? How are my neighbours to ensure the safety of their neighbours?

Comment: We would need to know your location to be able to tell you the rules/laws that apply to you.

Comment: "How are my neighbours to ensure the safety of their neighbours?" - Could you clarify what you're asking here? I'm not quite sure what you meant. Thanks.

Comment: I feel this should be re-worded. Instead of asking "what should my neighbours do",  the question should be "what can I do to protect my dog".

Answer (score 3):

This answer is part of [Pet's Spring Cleaning Campaign](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2331/spring-cleaning-campaign-on-pets-se?cb=1). This question is old, but this answer will still help people with the same problem.

---

**It is completely your neighbor's responsibility, legally (severity varies by area) and ethically.**

They are not your dogs. They are your neighbor's dogs. Your neighbor is expected to control them. They also belong on your neighbor's property, not yours.

> We have had a previous incident of attack by a Rottweiler on our short dog.

[edgarsnyder.com](https://www.edgarsnyder.com/dog-bite/attack-on-dog.html) legal firm says:

> - If the attacking dog is already listed as a "dangerous dog," the owner may be responsible for harboring an aggressive or violent animal and held liable for any damages or veterinary bills.
> - If the attacking dog is listed as "dangerous" and your dog has to be put down, the owner may be held responsible for the original amount you paid for your dog.
> - If other owner violated your state's leash laws, he or she may be held responsible for any veterinary costs.

*Immediately check with your neighbor to make sure the attacking dog has had all of its rabies shots.*

Your neighbor should also compensate (some depending on if you were also injured, which I don't know):

> - Medical treatment related to the attack.
> - Income lost due to missed work.
> - Property that was destroyed or damaged (eyeglasses, clothing, etc.).
> - Any lasting disability or scar.
> - Emotional suffering.

From [araglegal.com](https://www.araglegal.com/individuals/learning-center/topics/home-and-property/neighbor-dog-attacks).

Find a personal lawyer and sue if:

> - You have suffered injuries that require you to see a doctor, especially if you are going to require ongoing treatment such as surgeries or skin grafts.
> - You are coping with disfiguring injuries after being mauled by an animal.
> - You have missed work due to your injuries.
> - You believe you are going to be permanently disabled due to your injuries.
> - You are struggling with ongoing mental anguish such as post-traumatic stress and the inability to enjoy the things you once loved to do.

From [krwlawyers.com](https://www.krwlawyers.com/premises-liability-lawyers/dog-attack-lawyer/what-to-do-after-being-attacked-by-a-neighbors-dog/)

If you choose not to press legal charges or take any further action against your neighbors and their dog, here's how to ensure the safety of you, your dog, and your property:

> **How Can I Humanely Keep Neighbor Dogs Out Of My Yard?**
>
> 1. Entice Your Neighbor To Keep Their Dog Out Of Your Yard.
> 2. Understand Local Ordinances Regarding Roaming Dogs.
> 3. Remove Attractions To Neighborhood Dogs.
> 4. Clean Up Dog Exctrament [*sic*].
> 5. Try Bottled Water To Keep Dogs Away.
> 6. Remove Standing Water.
> 7. Use Dog Repellants to Keep Dogs Away.
> 8. Consider Automatic Repellants To Keep Dogs Away.
> 9. Build a fence.

From [countrypests.com](https://countrypests.com/how-can-i-humanely-keep-neighbor-dogs-out-of-my-yard/).

If you or your dog ever get attacked again, I would seriously consider hiring a lawyer.